# Caching Database Tables in Memory

Tags: c#, .net, database, caching

Edit:

> The reason I am looking if caching large data(entire database, or lots
>   of tables) possible is because database columns are encrypted,even for
>   different rows with different IV vectors of symetric rijndael key.
>   Thus SQL filtering is no option or indexing have no meaning. Also the application, actually it
>   is a framework for cloud and busisness applications, is being designed
>   as database independent as much as possible. You would suggest encrypt
>   only some columuns of a table only that holds really sensitive
>   information,such as email address or SSN, but that will make the
>   framework non-standard and you need to write new code for encrypted
>   columuns and for unencrypted columuns for each different application.
>   If there is no problem with caching, then I can do all operations on
>   object basis,dictionaries, linq etc. Ofcourse I have to sync database
>   and cache.

I plan to cache all or most database tables (encrypted) in memory.

I'm working on a cloud based application and it will have 100MB SQL Server / MySQL limit that will be shared by different clients. (So I can group them by client when caching; and even create smaller caching groups depend on the business model)

I have had no idea; how much time it would take to `SELECT * FROM` for 100000 rows, or 10 MB, or 20 MB of data etc. to fetch.

I made a quick search but could not find any benchmark that illustrates, "roughly"  duration to retrieve mass of rows.

My company is using a business software that is common to use in most small-medium size companies in modern world. It is said to be have active records everyday, and have only 20MB of MySQL data in 4.5 years.

I checked in MySQL Administrator and see that the largest table is inventory_movements and have 7MB of data with 45000 rows.

I used MySQL Query Browser and execute to select all records from this table. 
Software tool states that it took **0.4971 seconds**. Now I think I have an idea.

Fetching all rows (only pure `SELECT * FROM`, no filters, joins) in C# .NET; from SQL Server database, of 7MB Data - 45000 rows would result in similar duration, right? I am still OK, if it is 2 or 3 seconds.

This way; at least I have an idea; if I cache 100MB data; it would probably take 5 to 30 seconds.
(Data will not be decrypted during fetch)(It will be later decrypted in RAM when it is required to be)(I am aware of I loose most of database features. Queries will be based on objects in the cache) (I'm just started to think while writing this comment; if I succeed; I can even use xml as a free database source, cause I'm designing OR/M like functions for this application)

My question is;

There is no any problem to cache 100MB of data, as soon as I have enough resource right?
In other words; it is not weird to cache 100 MB, or even 500 MB, 1 GB as soon as I have memory resource ?

Secondly; Do you think my time calculations for fetching records with SELECT are optimistic?

At application start; I can cache the data; and manage the modified/added/deleted data both in cache and database without making frequent re-load caching.

Comment: Is your web server and your database server the same machine, or at least on the same LAN? Otherwise you need to factor in network transfer time to get the data from the DB server to the web server.

Comment: @BrianC Yes, they are in the same machine.

Comment: No specific performance issues but you know you need to cache?

Comment: I am going to use .NET caching system. When appfabric caching becomes more and more available, then it is an option to use. There is trend on migrating object base database models, such as entity frame work. I feel appfabric caching can be another trend in the following years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I made a quick search but could not find any bencmark that illustrates, "roughly" duration to retrieve mass of records.

And you never will. The rate at which a database responds is dependent upon so many variables it would be impossible to answer that for somebody. What's the tech specs of the servers? How many processors are you allowing the server to have? How did you index the table for reading?

As you can see, it can't be answered by somebody outside the organization.

> There is no any problem to cache 100MB of data, as soon as I have enough resource right? In other words; it is not wierd to cache 100MB, or even 500MB, 1GB as soon as I have memoery resource ?

In short, before I begin, you're looking at caching from the wrong perspective. Let's think for a minute about the *cache on the processor*. What's it used for? It's used to ensure that frequent operations occur faster right? Well, that's what data caching is used for - but that's only one side of the coin.

Let's talk about the second reason data caching exists. Let's say that you have an application that performs upward of 3M+ operations daily. Seems like a lot, but realistic in Fortune 500 companies yes? Well, caching is then used to ensure that data access to frequently used data - even transaction driven data - has no bottleneck visualized by the user.

See, generally speaking, the bottleneck will not be the database engine, the processor, RAM, cache, or even the network. Generally speaking, the bottleneck is I/O. Well, to read/write to a database 3M+ times a day is too much to expect from even the largest and most capable SAN's running 16K RPM drives.

So, what do we do, we spread the data across multiple machines (just in case one goes down *and* for load balancing) and we store it in RAM. Why? Because it's the fastest I/O possible, simple.

So, I said all that, to say this, it's likely that unless you're performing millions of operations a day you'll need to be caching 500MB or 1GB of data. In fact, it's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to perform because there's no *"here is what my application does"* in there, but it's possible you **don't need caching at all**.

Keep all of this in mind. Data caching is no trivial matter.

Comment: Application is a framework, for cloud and business applications. It is inspired with available technologies and best practices, re-shaping or designing it for our own application. For example entityframe work is OK, but at some point it does not meet your needs, then we decided to make very basic ORM that only targets our applications. Sometimes it takes more time to make an available application fit in your needs. As the framework itself wont go for public as a commerical product, we dont need to wory to cover all aspects of an OR/M, we can only focus what our application needs.

Comment: @freewill, and that's fine. I just wanted to point out that data caching is something that needs to be discussed in detail. It is no trivial matter. Now, based on what you stated I'm going to recommend that you cache *only* what is read *often* in your database. I say that because caching transactional objects creates significant complexities. Good luck in your endeavors and I hope I've given you some insight.

Comment: @Mike I truly appreciate your input and it gives me some insight. I will first go on to cache small data that can be managed easily. The main problem will be with reporting and LIKE % queries. Maybe small cache tables can be created that holds only columuns to be sorted or filtered and they keep reference of actual encrypted record on the database. I will thnik more about that side by design is shaped. I can also keep datetime columun decrypted that can help to reduce cache size. I will try as much as I can, to make a bulls eye shot to the encrypted database tables or columns

Comment: @freewill, one thing to consider, depending on your transaction load you may want to perform reporting from *the* database **or** a *warehoused* database. And as for the `LIKE` queries, you can perform those pretty easily with LINQ, but if it becomes a bottleneck **(which it may)**, perform those at the database as well. You'd still be limiting database access.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the database server and the web server are on the same machine, you won't suffer from network latency, so the only time considerations are the time to get the data out of the database, and the time to construct your objects within the web server. If you can make the object instantiations quick (which should be possible if they are representations of data tables) then your estimates are not wildly optimistic - this does depend a little though on the number of select statements you will need to do.

Personally I would only recommend caching data tables that rarely change unless the caches are in place to avoid heavy queries - I'll assume for the purposes of this post that your design decisions are sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to cache a lot of data, you need to take into account that doing operations on that data, eg sorting or searching will take time. Now if you never do those tasks, you've no need to worry.

On the other hand it may call in question the need to cache lots of data in memory, particularly as you've said the db is on the same server.

Caching is best used when you have data that is static and doesn't change. You process it & in your case that included decrypting it & store it, thereby saving future accesses from doing the same work everytime.

Comment: Actually there will be a lot of sorting filtering, by using dictionaries and lists with linq